# Conservation laws in quasilinear form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-equations

The system of conservation laws in one dimension (i.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}$) is given (in the conservative form): $$\partial_t U + \partial_x F(U)=0.$$

What exactly is quasilinear form of this system and when is it possible to write it from conservative form? Also, is DF(U) always linear?

Comment: If $F$ is differentiable, we can rewrite it as $\partial_t U + DF(U)\partial_x U = 0$, which is linear in $U$'s highest derivatives (here: first derivatives) and hence quasi-linear.

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that $DF(U)$ is always linear?

Comment: $DF(U)$ is, by definition of the derivative, a linear map $\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$, so $DF(U)\partial_x U$, is linear in $\partial_x U$, note that $DF(U)\partial_x U$ is in general not linear in $U$.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally find the answer
$$
U_t+A(U)U_x=0
$$
where $A=F'$

referring to page 2 in https://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/clawtut09.pdf